# Without using l’Hopital’s Rule, determine $\lim_{x\to\ 25} \frac{\sqrt x - 5}{x-25}$.

Tags: limits

Question:

Without using l’Hopital’s Rule, determine $$\lim_{x\to\ 25} \frac{\sqrt x - 5}{x-25}$$.

I don't know where to start. I tried the following

$$ \frac{\sqrt x - 5}{x - 25}  =  \frac{x - 25}{(x - 25)(\sqrt x + 25)} $$

but that doesn't help.

Comment: How would you find the derivative of $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ at the point $x=25$ by the limit definition of the derivative?

Comment: Are you really sure that "this doesn't help" ?

Comment: Bloody hell, I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

> $$x-25 = (\sqrt x)^2 - 5^2 = (\sqrt x-5)(\sqrt x+5)$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$x-25=(\sqrt x-5)(\sqrt x+5)$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$\forall x\ne{25}: \frac{\sqrt x - 5}{x - 25}  =  \frac{x - 25}{(x - 25)(\sqrt x + 5)}  =  \frac1{\sqrt x + 5} .$$

Comment: Shouldn't the conjugate be $\sqrt{x} + 5$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: it is. Read carefully, the OP made it in a clever way.

Comment: Then why didn't you get $\sqrt{x} + 5$ in the denominator?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: most probably because of a typo. :-) I should have proofread myself.

Answer (score 2):

Hint

Let $h=\sqrt x-5,x\to25\implies h\to0$

$x=(h+5)^2=25+h(h+10)$